# SwiftUI Core Data Object crashes when I call `date` property in list

Tags: swiftui, core-data, foreach

I am trying to display a list of CoreData entities (games) in a list. If I just call the `game.score`, or use any other combination of properties, everything is fine, but if I reference `game.date` in either the list or the `detailView` it points to, I get a crash whenever I delete or add items from the list, but not the first time.

I have tried leaving the list label blank, only using `game.score`, and using different combination of `game` properties. I have also tried replacing the `GameDetailView` with `BlankView`, which is just a black screen. Neither of these work if I’m using `game.date` in the label, but both work if I leave out `game.date`.

I think what’s happening is instead of creating or deleting a one `game` when I use those buttons, the `CoreData` is either replacing a previous `game` when a new one is created, or deleting multiple `games` when I delete one. When adding a new `game`, the list sometimes updates an existing `game`, rather than create a new one.

I will paste what I believe is the relevant code.

edit: I have figured out that my `addNewGame` func is creating games with the same id. Not sure yet if it is related to the date or not, but the problem only seems to persist when I include the date.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import CoreData
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
//    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
//    @FetchRequest(
//        entity: Club.entity(),
//        sortDescriptors:[])
//    private var clubs:FetchedResults<Club>
    
    
    
    @State private var shotClub = Club()
    @State private var ballClub = Club()
    @State private var showNewClub: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManagerModel
    //@State private var game = ""
    @AppStorage("NUMBER_KEY") var counter = 0
    @AppStorage("NUMBER_KEY") var putts = 0
    @State var roundStarted = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            ClubListView(counter: $counter, putts: $putts, roundStarted: $roundStarted)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                }
    
            RoundView(counter: $counter, putts: $putts, roundStarted: $roundStarted)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "flag")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct RoundView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Game.entity(),
        sortDescriptors:[])
    private var games:FetchedResults<Game>
    @State private var game = Game()
    @Binding var counter: Int
    @Binding var putts: Int
    @Binding var roundStarted: Bool
    @State var today = Date()
    //@State var golfCourse = ""
    var body: some View {
        //var golfCourse = "test"
        let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9
        VStack {
            if !roundStarted {
                Button(action: {
                    roundStarted = true
                }, label: {
                    Text("Start a Round")
                }).padding(.top)
            }
            if roundStarted {
                VStack {
                    Text("\(counter)")
                        .font(.system(size: 100, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    Text("Score")
                        .font(.title)
                        .frame(width: width, height: 50, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .border(Color.primary, width: 0.5)
                    HStack{
                        Text("Putts: ")
                    }
                }.frame(width: width)
                    .padding()
                    .background(.quaternary)
                    .cornerRadius(10, antialiased: true)
                Button(action: {
                    roundStarted = false
                    today = Date.now
                    self.addNewGame(today: today, putts: putts, counter: counter)
                    counter = 0
                }, label: {
                    Text("Finish Round")
                })
            }

            if games.count > 0{
                NavigationView{
                    List {
                        ForEach(games) {game in 
                            NavigationLink(destination: BlankView(), label: {
                                Text("\(game.score)")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("\(game.date)")
                            })
                        }.onDelete(perform: deleteGame)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
    }
    private func addNewGame(today: Date, putts: Int, counter: Int) -> Void {
        let newGame = Game(context: viewContext)
        newGame.id = UUID()
        newGame.score = counter
        newGame.putts = putts
        newGame.date = today
        
        //newClub.nfcTag = ""
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
            print(viewContext)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func deleteGame(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let game = games[index]
            viewContext.delete(game)
        }
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Handle the error here
            print("Error deleting game: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct RoundView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let testCounter = 10
        @State var counter = testCounter
        @State var roundStarted = true
        @State var putts = 10
//        let testGame = Game(context: PersistanceController.preview.container.viewContext)
        RoundView(counter: $counter, putts: $putts, roundStarted: $roundStarted)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Foundation

@objc(Game)
public class Game: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var score: Int
    @NSManaged public var putts: Int
    @NSManaged public var date: Date
    //@NSManaged public var golfCourse: String
}

@objc(Club)
public class Club: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var name: String
    //@NSManaged public var yardsNum: Int
    @NSManaged public var strokes: Int
    @NSManaged public var putter: Bool
    @NSManaged public var strokesList: [Int]
    //@NSManaged public var averageYardage: Int
    @NSManaged public var nfcTag: String
}

extension Club: Identifiable {
//    var yards: Yards{
//        get {
//            Yards(rawValue: Int(yardsNum)) ?? .normal
//        }
//        
//        set {
//            self.yardsNum = Int(newValue.rawValue)
//        }
//    }
    var strokesStandardDeviation: Double {
        guard !strokesList.isEmpty else {
            return 0.0 // or another appropriate value when the list is empty
        }
        let mean = Double(strokesList.reduce(0, +)) / Double(strokesList.count)
        let squaredDifferences = strokesList.map { pow(Double($0) - mean, 2) }
        let variance = squaredDifferences.reduce(0, +) / Double(strokesList.count)
        return sqrt(variance)
    }
    var averageYardage: Int {
        guard !strokesList.isEmpty else {
            return 0
        }
        let numStrokes = strokesList.count
        let sumArray = strokesList.reduce(0,+)
        let averageYardage = sumArray / numStrokes
        return averageYardage
    }
}
enum Yards: Int {
    case normal = 0
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

import CoreData

struct PersistanceController {
    static let shared = PersistanceController()
    
    static var preview: PersistanceController = {
        let result = PersistanceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
//        for index in 0..<10 {
//            
//        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        
        let clubEntity = NSEntityDescription()
        clubEntity.name = "Club"
        clubEntity.managedObjectClassName = "Club"
        
        let idAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        idAttribute.name = "id"
        idAttribute.type = .uuid
        clubEntity.properties.append(idAttribute)
        
        let nameAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        nameAttribute.name = "name"
        nameAttribute.type = .string
        clubEntity.properties.append(nameAttribute)
        
        let putterAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        putterAttribute.name = "putter"
        putterAttribute.type = .boolean
        clubEntity.properties.append(putterAttribute)
        
        let strokesNumAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        strokesNumAttribute.name = "strokes"
        strokesNumAttribute.type = .integer32
        clubEntity.properties.append(strokesNumAttribute)
        
        let strokesListAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        strokesListAttribute.name = "strokesList"
        strokesListAttribute.type = .transformable
        clubEntity.properties.append(strokesListAttribute)
        
        /////////////////////////////////
        
        let gameEntity = NSEntityDescription()
        gameEntity.name = "Game"
        gameEntity.managedObjectClassName = "Game"
        
        let puttsAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        puttsAttribute.name = "putts"
        puttsAttribute.type = .integer32
        gameEntity.properties.append(puttsAttribute)
        
        let dateAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        dateAttribute.name = "date"
        dateAttribute.type = .date
        gameEntity.properties.append(dateAttribute)
        
        let scoreAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
        scoreAttribute.name = "score"
        scoreAttribute.type = .integer32
        gameEntity.properties.append(scoreAttribute)
        
//        let golfCourseAttribute = NSAttributeDescription()
//        golfCourseAttribute.name = "golfCourse"
//        golfCourseAttribute.type = .string
//        gameEntity.properties.append(golfCourseAttribute)
        
        gameEntity.properties.append(idAttribute)
        
        
        
        
        let model = NSManagedObjectModel()
        model.entities = [clubEntity, gameEntity]
        //model.entities = [gameEntity]
        
        
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ClubToDo", managedObjectModel: model)
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.viewContext
            .automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {(storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The error message reads:

"There was an uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException with reason: Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Collection view: <SwiftUI.UpdateCoalescingCollectionView: 0x14284e400; baseClass = UICollectionView: frame = (0 0; 328 299); clipsToBounds = YES, autoresize = W+H gestureRecognizers = NSArray:0x281709ef0; backgroundcolor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x280c77b00; name = systemGroupedBackgroundColor>; layer = <<CALayer: 0x281902260>; contentOffset: {0,0}; contentSize: {328,226.5}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 50, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: 0x141e4cd60>; dataSource: <*TtGC7SwiftUI31UICollectionViewListCoordinatorGVS_28CollectoinViewListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManagerBoxs2*_: 0x141e3f8a0>>"

edit: I have found a workaround, but I think there is probably a way to actually solve this problem so I won't put my solution in the answer. My workaround is to condition that `counter != 0`. A score of zero should never need to be recorded, and this stops the user from creating multiple games in quick succession, which crashes the app. I think this error will only occur when `games` are created quickly. I have not been able to recreate the crash since adding this condition.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @jhbetts for readability, please [edit] your question with extra info, don’t put it in the comments. See also [ask].